# Setting initial values to Angular form group for testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I'm writing a unit test for an Angular 7 reactive form that has its input values pre-filled with server data on ngInit. How can I set the values of this form so that it doesn't five me a "value undefined" error during testing?

This is my form being pre-filled on ngOnInit:

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [ this.user.id ],
  first_name: [this.user.first_name, Validators.required],
  last_name: [this.user.last_name, Validators.required],
});
```

This is the current (barebones) test code for the form:

```
//import modules

describe('UserListItemComponent', () => {
  let component: UserListItemComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserListItemComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      MaterialModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      FormsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
      UserListItemComponent,
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
  })
  .compileComponents();
  }));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserListItemComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  component.userForm.setValue({
    id: 123,
    first_name: "john",
    last_name: "smith",
  });
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

However, the Karma test runner still says it's undefined for id. Is it because it's not pre-filling the data with `setValue`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `fixture.detectChanges();` will call `ngOnInit()`, but the `user` property is undefined. You can change your code like this:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserListItemComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
const user = {
//your properties here
};
component.user = user;
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function to update the form values, when testing:

```
function updateForm(id: string, first_name: string, last_name: string) {
        component.userForm.controls['id'].setValue(id);
        component.userForm.controls['first_name'].setValue(first_name);
        component.userForm.controls['last_name'].setValue(last_name);
    }
```

In the test case:

```
 it('should create form', () => {
  updateForm('1','john','smith');
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  expect(component.userForm.value).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Or you can pass the `user` object to component using:

```
`component.user = mockUser;`
```

And the form values will be set onInit.

Most likely the error you have because of undefined `user` property on component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it's not working. I get a "Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined" error. When I log `fixture.component` it returns this: `{"formBuilder":{},"isEditing":false,"select":{"_isScalar":false,"observers":[],"closed":false,"isStopped":false,"hasError":false,"thrownError":null,"__isAsync":false},"delete":{"_isScalar":false,"observers":[],"closed":false,"isStopped":false,"hasError":false,"thrownError":null,"__isAsync":false},"edit":{"_isScalar":false,"observers":[]}`

Comment: in `id: [ this.user.id ]`, user is injected using `@input`. Does that have anything to do with my error?

Comment: if that is the case you can mock the necessary data to create your `form`. Make sure your component receives what it needs `onInit`

Answer (score 0):

you can make:

```
component.ngOnInit();
component.form.setValue({
  status : StatusEnum.AKTIV_ABSCHLUSSVERMITTLER,
  name : "name",
  vorname : "vorname",
  betreuernummer: "23213",
  geschaeftspartnernummer: "321313"
});
component.getColorForTabel();
```

need call component.ngOnInit(); before setValue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).